# Promises not working after re entering the page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, promise

I have an app with Ionic 2 that contains a 2 pages. when I click on a button in the home page, it send me to a page in which we have a map that locates the current position and the nearby locations. All locations are displayed, but when I return to the home page and re-click the button, the map in the second page shows just the current positions and not the nearby. 
this is the code that initializes the second page :

```
ionViewDidLoad(){

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  let mapLoaded = this.maps.init(this.mapElement.nativeElement, this.pleaseConnect.nativeElement);
  let locationsLoaded = this.locations.load();

  Promise.all([
    mapLoaded,
    locationsLoaded
  ]).then((result) => {
    let locations = result[1];

    for(let location of locations){
      this.maps.addMarker(location.latitude, location.longitude,'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
    }

  });

});
```

Comment: Have you tried your function in the ionViewWillEnter?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an observable with the route;

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  });
}
```

you can also try reading this article; may help. 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/observables_array_operations.html

Comment: Thank you! could you please explain to me this code and how to change my code to your code because I am new to angular??

Comment: You'll need to put it in your router, If you are not sure what that is please if you have not done so do this tutorial https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: I am also new to angular2 and this has helped my understanding immensely, On that same page on the side menu you can find the "cookbook" and look at "router" and "observables" 
teaching you how to do those is outside the scope of your question though. and has been answered on here a few times Im sure.

Comment: If this has helped you identify the issue, or lead you to a different question don't forget to mark my answer :)

Comment: Ok James Warren, I will try this and answer you in a while.

Comment: @thenino did you managed to solve this? If yes, can you post how you did it?